# ORA-00913: too many values error when I run a query in SQL*Plus

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus, ora-00913

I am trying to get the dname, loc, and count the ename's, plus I want to include the sal from the table. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong.

Heres my statement with the error I get

```
 SQL> select dname, loc, (select count(ename), sal from emp where DEPTNO =   dept.deptno) as Number_of_people  from dept;
 select dname, loc, (select count(ename), sal from emp where DEPTNO = dept.deptno) as  Number_of_people  from dept
                *
 ERROR at line 1:
 ORA-00913: too many values


 SQL>
```

Heres my table

```
SQL> select empno, ename, job, hiredate, sal from emp;

 EMPNO ENAME      JOB       HIREDATE         SAL
---------- ---------- --------- --------- ----------
  7839 KING       PRESIDENT 17-NOV-81       5000
  7698 BLAKE      MANAGER   01-MAY-81       2850
  7782 CLARK      MANAGER   09-JUN-81       2450
  7566 JONES      MANAGER   02-APR-81       2975
  7654 MARTIN     SALESMAN  28-SEP-81       1250
  7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN  20-FEB-81       1600
  7844 TURNER     SALESMAN  08-SEP-81       1500
  7900 JAMES      CLERK     03-DEC-81        950
  7521 WARD       SALESMAN  22-FEB-81       1250
  7902 FORD       ANALYST   03-DEC-81       3000
  7369 SMITH      CLERK     17-DEC-80        800

 EMPNO ENAME      JOB       HIREDATE         SAL
 ---------- ---------- --------- --------- ----------
  7788 SCOTT      ANALYST   09-DEC-82       3000
  7876 ADAMS      CLERK     12-JAN-83       1100
  7934 MILLER     CLERK     23-JAN-82       1300

 14 rows selected.

 SQL>
```

Heres the second table

```
SQL> select * from dept;

DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
    10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
    20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
    30 SALES          CHICAGO
    40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON

 SQL>
```

Comment: Do you want total Salary per department?

Comment: why do people post a solution then erace it if its not picked? I picked the one that best fit what I was looking for the solution that was eraced might be a better one for someone else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get number of people and total Salary, try this...

```
 select dept.dname, dept.loc, 
        count(emp.ename) as Number_of_people, sum(emp.sal) as Total_Salary
 from emp 
 join dept on emp.DEPTNO = dept.deptno
 group by dept.dname,dept.loc
```

You can get other things as well

```
 select dept.dname, dept.loc, 
        count(emp.ename) as Number_of_people, 
        sum(emp.sal) as Total_Salary,
        avg(emp.sal) as Average_salary,
        min(emp.hiredate) as First_dept_hire,
        max(emp.hireDate) as Last_dept_hire
 from emp 
 join dept on emp.DEPTNO = dept.deptno
 group by dept.dname,dept.loc
```

Comment: As an added note, you can use a `right join` if you want to list departments which have no employees.

Comment: How could I choose to pick the employees that were hired between Feb 20, 1981 - May 1, 1981

Comment: I am sure my questions are very basic but I am fairly new to sql, trying to learn as I go.

Comment: @user `where hiredate between '20-FEB-81' AND '01-MAY-81'`

Answer (score 3):

The scalar (inline) cursor can only have only one value in its projection.

If you want to have more than one value, use a join and aggregate all the values, [as Sparky suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372712/error-when-i-run-a-query-in-sqlplus/7372746#7372746).